# saga_gui.exe identified as malware by antivirus when downloaded from OSGeo4W

Tags: qgis, saga, osgeo4w

I downloaded QGIS 2.6.1-2 (Brighton) yesterday from OSGeo4W-setup-x86.exe using the advanced installation option on a machine running on windows 7 professional. The download worked Ok except for saga 2.1.2-1 which I was really looking for. At first the saga package was identified as malware and its download was blocked by my free Antivirus system (Avast). When I decided to disable the Antivirus for a few minutes to allow for the download it then worked fine. However, I felt uneasy about the whole thing so to check, I have run an antivirus scan and it identifies saga_gui.exe as Win32:Malware-gen. If instead I choose saga 2.0.8-5, I do not have this problem but I believe I need the 2.1 version to do add polygon attributes to points. 
Has anybody else experienced these issues? Is there a way around this?

Comment: _"OSGeo4W-setup-w86.exe"_, should it not be OSGeo4W-setup-**x**86.exe? Can you provide a link to where you downloaded the installer from please? Hopefully the moderators can identify the issue.

Comment: Apologies Joseph for a delayed answer. You are correct I did download 'OSGeo4W-setup-x86.exe' and not 'OSGeo4W-setup-w86.exe' as I mistakenly wrote. I will edit my question to get rid of the typo. I downloaded it from this link: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/. And I confirm that even when re-installing, saga_gui.exe was again identified as malware by Avast.

Comment: Have you tried with a different antivirus software as well?

Comment: No need to apologise Lopaz :) I do not use Avast so I cannot confirm this. As @AndreJ has mentioned, you could try using another antivirus software. It could be that Avast is set to a very sensitive heuristic setting which highlights a _possible_ malware.

Comment: You might try this online checker: http://www.garyshood.com/virus/. But they are restricted to 10MB of file size.

Comment: ClamWin does not report any infection on the file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments AndreJ and Joseph. I did not try with another antivirus software. I was under the impression it was not a good idea to have multiple antivirus softwares. The online checker is a great idea but the zip file that it came from is larger than 10MB unfortunately. Great to know that ClamWin does not find any infection. Seems like it might be a false positive

Comment: I occasionally have our corporate Symantec Endpoint virus software identify exe's as potential viruses. If I am confident that it is from a secure source, I just add an exception and the virus software just ignores it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identification of GIS programs as being suspicious by antivirus software is best reported to the GIS developers and antivirus vendors to sort out between them.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can try the official SAGA download from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/

and see if your virus scanner likes that more. They already offer SAGA 2.1.4.